# Wordpress action hook - Didn't work

Tags: php, wordpress, hook

would you help to solved this issue I tried to create a new hook in wordpress do_action and add_action.

Here is my code below

```
    $arg1 = 'args test 1';
    $arg2 = 'args test 2';

    do_action('action1',$arg1, $arg2);

    function test_function($arg1, $arg2) {
       echo $arg1.$arg2;
    }

    add_action('action1','test_function',10,2);
```

When I tried to run my scripts nothing's happen it should display the $arg1 and $args2 ,What should be the problem is there anything wrong with the scripts ?

Comment: is this code being placed in your functions.php file?

Answer (score 0):

That is all about places, you run action before you set that

Try like this :

```
$arg1 = 'args test 1';
$arg2 = 'args test 2';


function test_function($arg1, $arg2) {
   echo $arg1.$arg2;
}

add_action('action1','test_function',10,2);

do_action('action1',$arg1, $arg2);
```

now thats should work